# Mat AutoComplete Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I get the list but once type any of my data it gives me an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'valueChanges')` how to fix this? i get the name of my form array and i think that's correct anyone can teach me or answer me.

```
filteredOptions:any;
options = [];



this.serviceLogForm = this.fb.group({
      id:[0],
      Name:[],
      ArrayForm:this.fb.array([this.CreateArray()])
    })

CreateArray(){
    return this.fb.group({
        item:['']
    })
  }

ngOninit{
this.ArrayForm.get('item').valueChanges.subscribe(response => {
      console.log('data is ', response);
      this.filterData(response);
    })
}

filterData(enterData){
    this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(item => {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(enterData.toLowerCase()) > -1
    })
  }

getData(){
  this.services.dataList(true).subscribe((response) => {
    this.options = response;
    this.filteredOptions = response;
    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Here's my services where i map the items of my list and get the specific data

```
dataList(isActive: Boolean){
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('isActive', String(isActive));
        return this.http.get(this.appsetting.baseURL + 'myList/list',{params})
        .pipe(
          map((response:any) => response.items.map(items =>items['Name']))
        );
      }
```

Comment: `ArrayForm` is a `FormArray`, i.e. an array. So you'll want something like `(this.ArrayForm.at(0) as FormGroup).get('item').valueChanges`. See api for [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

Comment: @AndrewAllen it works now i thought you need to declare in first in ngOninit(index) to call the at()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See api for [FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

ArrayForm is a FormArray, i.e. an array.

So you'll want something like

```
(this.ArrayForm.at(0) as FormGroup).get('item').valueChanges
```

> i thought you need to declare in first in ngOninit(index) to call the at()

Your class has constructed the `serviceLogForm` when `ngOnInit` runs, so it has full structure:

```
this.serviceLogForm = this.fb.group({
    id:[0],
    Name:[],
    ArrayForm:this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({ item:[''] }) // <--------- index 0 of array
    ])
})
```

Question to ask yourself - If you'll only ever have one form group in this array than why use a form array?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from your ngOnInit function.

It seems you don't have a `ArrayForm` variable in your component.

But the real error comes from

```js
this.ArrayForm.get('item').valueChanges
```

Where `this.ArrayForm.get('item')` is undefined. Try to resolve that.

Comment: how to fix that? sorry im newbie

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayForm` has no control with name `item` so `this.ArrayForm.get('item')` returns undefined.

As a side note, your variables are not everywhere correctly typed and variable names doesn't follow lover camel case.

Comment: what should i do?